# Java - IllegalArguemtnException

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception

this might as well be a stupid error on my part, but I have an error.
When I try to read the RGB values of a pixel in a BufferedImage.

I do this:

```
Color col = new Color(c);

red[x][y] = (byte) col.getRed();
green[x][y] = (byte) col.getGreen();
blue[x][y] = (byte) col.getBlue();
```

But, when I attempt to read from them with a JFrame's g.setColor

```
g.setColor(sprite.GetPixel((byte) x, (byte) y));

g.drawLine(object.x + x, object.y + y, object.x + x, object.y + y);
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Color parameter outside of expected range: Green
    at java.awt.Color.testColorValueRange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Color.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Color.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at fi.xman3.Game.SpriteCreator.GetPixel(SpriteCreator.java:23)
    at fi.xman3.Game.Window.paintComponent(Window.java:32)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I can provide more info on the classes if needed.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16497487/2101702

Comment: The exception message is very specific what the problem is, so what do you not understand?

Comment: The one Archer gave me worked great after I did some code changing. Thanks!